# Trigger an on-click overlay automatically once per user per ip

Tags: javascript, arrays

Like the title suggests, I have an overlay modal window on one of my websites. It fires every time a user clicks on a specific button. Am I able to somehow trigger that specfic button automatically once per user/ip so I can display that modal at least once for everyone, even if they don't click it? It's a good way to increase social-media fans and I noticed many websites are using this method. Is there any script that simply does that? I will provide code if necessarly although I don't see how it can help since this is more like a general matter.

Comment: Just use a cookie to determine if you've shown the modal window or not.

Comment: One solution if you use cookies. check for the cookie if the cookie is not found fire the event, else you can store every vistor's ip into a db and cross check that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like you want two things...

1. to trigger the modal to show regardless of whether the user clicks or not

   window.load(function () {
      //execute your modal popup here.
   });

   Note:  You'll need JQuery for this.
2. to limit the window to only appearing once per user.

   If your users are using a login, I'd suggest creating a new table for promos, possibly named, 'UserPromos' and create a bit field for this modal like, 'modalshown' and set it to false '0', for all users. Then, merely send that value to your page in a hidden input field, access that value from JS and if that value is '0' then show the modal with your script above and if it's '1' then don't.

   Your server side code would update the value for the UserPromos.modalshown for that user in the db.

   If your users are just visitors to the site, then you must use a JS cookie.

Comment: Actually, I already have a JS cookie and I already implemented it with your code and it does work. No, my users are just visitors; it's a startup so we wanna get fans thus we wanna show it once per user. Thanks.